# video stabilisation of tripod-taken video with many fast moving objects

Tags: linux, stabilisation

Is there a way - in Linux - to stabilize with respect to a certain edge or region in the video? My situation:

I have a video taken with a tripod (well, not exactly, the camera is suspended and slightly shaken and rotating, but not by much).

In the video there are a lot of moving objects - I want the image to be stabilized according to a jagged edge. I've tried `transcode` with `vid.stab`, specifically `transcode -J transform=tripod=1 ...`, but there is much more movement in the image than before stabilisation.

As stated at the beginning of this question: Can I define a region in my image that is a non-moving object and stabilize according to this object?

If there is no linux software to do this, is there any other free (preferably open source) software that can do this?